# intl tel input - var allCountries - java to html to javascript - how to pass a String in a var and use it in js

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, intl-tel-input

I don't know how to solve this. I created a java method which create a String with all the information in the language of the local :

```
public String getAllCountries(){
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("[ ");
ResourceBundle bundlePays = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_PAYS, localeBean.getLocale());
for(int i = 0; i< bundlePays.keySet().size(); i++ ){
String key = (String) bundlePays.keySet().toArray()[i];
String nomPays = traduirePays(key);
ResourceBundle bundlePrefix = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_PREFIX);

        if ((AieStringUtils.getSafeBundleString(bundlePrefix, key)) != key){

            String prefix = bundlePrefix.getString(key);
            sb.append("[");
            sb.append("\"" + nomPays + "\"" + "," + "\""+ key +"\"" + "," + "\""+ prefix + "\"");
            if (i!=bundlePays.keySet().size()-1){
                sb.append("], ");
            }else{
                sb.append("] ");
            }
        }
    }
    sb.append(" ]");
    String allCountries = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(allCountries);
    return allCountries;

}
```

I put the result in my xhtml like this :

```
<inputTextArea type="hidden" name="allCountries" id="allCountries" 
                        value="#{pageInfoPerso.allCountries}"/>
```

It gives me this kind of result :

```
[ ["Vanuatu","VU","678"], ["Vietnam","VN","84"], ["Equateur","EC","593"], ["Iles Vierges Americaines","VI","1"], ["Algerie","DZ","213"], ["Iles Vierges Britanniques","VG","1"], ["Venezuela","VE","58"] ]
etc
```

Then, I want to use this in intlTelInput.js
So, I decided to put the var inside the js and to insert it that way from the xhtml :

```
<h:outputScript>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {                     
                     $("#phoneNumber").intlTelInput({
                     var allCountries={allCountries : document.getElementById("allCountries").innerHTML};
                        utilsScript: "/js/utils.js"
                    });
                     $("#phoneNumber2").intlTelInput({
                        utilsScript: "/js/utils.js"
                    });
                });

    </h:outputScript>
```

It's not working and I get this error : 
"SyntaxError: missing : after property id"

*I have to probably tell you at this point that I never do any front and never touched Javascript before :/*

I also tried directly in

```
 the js file to put my var like this at the top of it :

//var allCountries = document.getElementById("allCountries").innerHTML;
//
//for (var i = 0; i < allCountries.length; i++) {
//    var c = allCountries[i];
//    allCountries[i] = {
//        name: c[0],
//        iso2: c[1],
//        dialCode: c[2],
//        priority: c[3] || 0,
//        areaCodes: c[4] || null
//    };
//}
```

It didn't work either and I got this message :

"this.countries[0] is undefined intl tel input "

Can somebody explain to me how I can pass my String from java to html to Js please ? 
Thank you so much in advance. It's been two days I'm searching, I'm going crazy.